# Blank screen at login if vga isn't plugged in (openchrome driver)

Tags: 16.04, drivers, vga, openchrome

I upgraded my laptop to Xubuntu 16.04. I used a generic driver for my video card with Xubuntu 14.04, that worked, but this time I tried the correct one (xserver-xorg-video-openchrome, for my VIA Chrome 9 HC VN896). It worked perfectly (when I install video driver I was with VGA plugged in, not using, just plugged). I unpluged VGA and rebooted my computer, but instead of login screen I got stuck at a completely blank screen (no backlight at all). I've tried everything, reinstall the driver without plugged in VGA, reconfigure xorg.conf and nothing worked. The only way I can use my laptop is conecting VGA (don't need to turn on the TV) and boot, at login screen I can disconnect and works perfectly. Some help, please.
Just to make clear: I never turned on my TV (VGA connection) during this whole process (always using my laptop monitor), I was just luck to figure out that I need VGA connected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. even if the monitor is off, ubuntu still registers that the monitor is there. and identified it as the default screen. IE it confused the external and the laptop screen.

you need to delete the monitor profile : ~/.config/monitors.xml.

if using plasma5  :   Removing ~/.local/share/kscreen/

then shutdown. start up with external disconnected and ubuntu will reconfigure the monitors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't work. I 've deleted ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/displays.xml. Now there's another display,xml but I have to plug VGA in again. Any other sugestions?

Answer (score 0):

I created a dummy vga plug, like this one: http://www.geeks3d.com/20091230/vga-hack-how-to-make-a-vga-dummy-plug/
But instead of using resistors in vga, I put them in DVI conectors side. Works very well. 
I know that isn't the best solution, but my computer is very old and so its video card. It's the best option since I don't know how to debbug a driver.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

1. Remove the OpenChrome/UniChrome driver completely:

   ```sh
   sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove xserver-xorg-video-openchrome
   ```
2. Uncomment (that is, remove the `#` character from) the line `#GRUB_TERMINAL=console in the file /etc/default/grub`:

   ```sh
   sudo sed -i '/^#GRUB_TERMINAL=console/s/^#//' /etc/default/grub
   ```
3. Then update Grub:

   ```sh
   sudo update-grub
   ```
4. Reboot your system.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Ubuntu 18.04 upgrade fixed the problem.